# unexpected behavior with template function overloading

Tags: c++

So i have the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/dvKe5oTfK) snippet which compiles correctly:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&>
  _Up
  __declval(long);

//template<typename _Tp>
//  _Tp
//  __declval(char);

template<typename _Tp>
auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));

int main()
{
    declval<int>;
    return 0;
}
```

and i have [this](https://godbolt.org/z/We1MWsMvW) one, which for some reason it doesn't:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&>
  _Up
  __declval(long);

template<typename _Tp>
  _Tp
  __declval(char);
  //but if we change char to int it works

template<typename _Tp>
auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));

int main()
{
    declval<int>;
    return 0;
}
```

The error i get with the second snippet according to clang:

> :26:5: error: reference to overloaded function could not be
> resolved; did you mean to call it?

But when i replace the __declval(char) with __declval(int) the error disappears. I've been scratching my head for some time now, any clues about the underlying cause of this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into effectively the same problem as the following, simpler and equally broken, program:

```
void foo(long) {}
void foo(char) {}

int main() {
    foo(0);
}
```

The error is a lot clearer here though:

> :5:5: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous

The issue is that `0`, being an `int`, is equally valid as a `char` as it is as a `long`. In both cases, an implicit conversion is required. Since neither is preferable to the other, the call is *ambiguous*.

There are 3 ways to fix this:

1. Make sure there is only one overload that is implicitly callable from an `int`. That's how the original snippet works.
2. Provide an overload that does not need an implicit conversion for the parameter used at the callsite. This is what using `__declval(int)` does.
3. Use a `long` literal instead of an `int` one at the callsite. So that `__declval(long)` is called without the need for an implicit conversion.

```
auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0L));
```